# GraphQL: Prevent Sending Data Multiple Times by Referencing JSON Elements

Tags: json, graphql

When I do a GraphQL query like this:

```
posts {
   id
   title
   author {
     name
   }
}
```

I will get some posts, and each of these posts contains the author. Imagine the author did not only contain `name`, but huge amounts of data.

Some posts will have the same `author`. **I am looking for a way to send each distinct author only once**, and for all the posts having the same author as a post before, to only send a reference to the first author.

Is this possible? I am not even sure how this problem is called. Is it something GraphQL can solve, or is it something I need to do to my JSON payload on top of/after GraphQL?

Comment: It's not possible to re-normalize the JSON that is returned in a GraphQL payload. If you ask for a denormalized object you're going to get a denormalized object.